# Changing value of passed values java

Tags: java, methods, parameters, parameter-passing, swap

Im experimenting with some stuff, and i was just wondering if thwre is any way to modify the source of the parameter values passed to a method? Like if i have this method for swapping two values:

```
void swap(int i, int j) {
    int temp = i;
    i = j;
    j = temp;
}
```

Is there any way to make it so that the integers passed to the method get changed as they are modified in the method?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480

Comment: The short answer is no.  Each method call has its own little space on the stack, where the method arguments are stored.  A method can't change values on the stack that are outside its own space.